# How to generate a list from a list of objects in python?

Tags: python

I have a class called Person formatted like this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first, last, number, zip):
        self.first = first
        self.lst = last
        self.number = number
        self.zip = zip
```

I have a list of Person's called People

```
People = []
person1, person2
people.append(person1)
people.append(person2)
```

I want to create a new list that contains all numbers in People in the same order that they appear in People. Currently my solution is to do this:

```
numbers = []
for person in People:
    numbers.append(person.number)
```

Is this the quickest way to achieve this? Or is there a more efficient/python-like way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List comprehension vs map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map)

Comment: Work through a tutorial on "list comprehension".  If you have a general need for a list of all numbers, then your class likely needs to be refactored to support the use case.

Comment: May you comment on what scenarios I would have to refactor the code? Julien's answer works for creating a list of numbers. @Prune

Comment: (1) Refactoring is out of scope for Stack Overflow, unless you provide a specific attempt; (2) since you haven't specified your use case, I would have no way to assist your refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension:

```
numbers = [person.number for person in People]
```